# iPhone 6 Plus show strange lines in UITableViewCell next to the accessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-6-plus

I have a `UITableView` that is showing some strange thin grey lines next to the accessory view. This ONLY happens on the `plus`, no other iPhone shows this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems to have something to do with the `imageView` that is assigned to the cell. Some images cause the line, others don't, seemingly based on their dimensions.

Has anyone else seen this or know how to get rid of it?

Comment: I also have this problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @llario - No, I never found a solution.

Comment: Is there a common thread between the images that cause the problem and the ones that don't?

Comment: @iamataptool No, I thought that might be the issue, but there was no correlation.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this when using a UITableView that was partially covered with an SWRevealViewController.

When the calculated value of the tableview width was a decimal number, artifact lines between the content of a UITableViewCell and the accessory view would appear.

The solution was to make sure that size calculations for the view were rounded to whole numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that line is from the right edge of the cell's content view. I don't know how it works, but my solution was:

`cell.backgroundColor = .clear`